# Dynamically adding lifecycle methods in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular 5 application which has a class which uses a 3rd party library for one of it's child templates. I'm using 2 of the templates in the component and wanted to override different behavior for both of them, while keeping the view templates consistent (to avoid duplicating a 3rd party template twice, which will not get updated when the library changes...). Here's a snippet from the template:

```
<tree #bookmap [value]="bookmapModel"></tree>
<tree #repository [value]="repositoryModel"></tree>
```

And in the controller I'm setting overriding the library's method `onNodeClick(event: any, node: TreeNode)` here:

```
@ViewChild('repository') set repo(tree: Tree) {
  if(tree) {
    tree.onNodeClick = this.onNodeClick.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Which as expected, does exactly as I want and works perfectly. For the other one, I want to override an angular lifecycle function (ngOnChanges), specifically one which was not defined in the library class's declaration (I mean to say that the class declaration does not include the `implement OnChanges` line). I tried doing the same thing:

```
@ViewChild('bookmap') set bookmap(tree: Tree) {
  if(tree) {
    tree.ngOnChanges = this.onChanges.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Which gives a compilation error, which is logically should. Then I tried using the property notation and the prototype:

```
@ViewChild('bookmap') set bookmap(tree: Tree) {
  if(tree) {
    tree['ngOnChanges'] = this.onChanges.bind(this);
  }
}
```

and

```
@ViewChild('bookmap') set bookmap(tree: Tree) {
  if(tree) {
    Tree.prototype['ngOnChanges'] = this.onChanges.bind(this);
  }
}
```

Which appear to be equivalent and I get no compilation problems, but get a runtime error here

`ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Is there a way to do what I want adding a lifecycle function? From the error, I can infer it *is* being set but not being run  (an error is thrown) when the lifecycle loop encounters the functions.

Comment: Have you tried `tree['ngOnChanges']`?

Comment: @cgTag yeah, that was a copy and paste typo, I'll correct the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely because the `tree` instance is no longer receiving calls to `ngOnChanges`. So it's internal state is broken. A good reason to *not* do what you're doing, but if you must then try this instead.

```
@ViewChild('bookmap') set bookmap(tree: Tree | OnChanges) {
    if(tree) {
       const previousOnChanges = tree.ngOnChanges;
       tree.ngOnChanges = (changes: SimpleChanges) => {
           if(previousOnChanges) {
               previousOnChanges(changes);
           }
           this.onChanges(changes);
       }
    }
}
```

I have no idea if this will yield the results you expect.

FYI: If you define the type as `Tree | OnChanges` then the `ngOnChanges` should not generate a compile error if you reference it.

Comment: Doesn't this lead to a compilation error if `Tree` didn't define `ngOnchanges`? And otherwise, doesn't this lead to an infinite recursive loop if it did define it?

Comment: @uberhaxed no infinite loop because you are calling the *old* function reference.

Comment: a but off topic, but I'm pretty sure you'd need to use a IIFE and return a function for that to work. The current form will store a reference at line 3 and this reference will be updated immediately in line 4, which will be use when the function is called later at runtime.

Comment: @uberhaxed no, line 4 does not change the value of `previousOnChanges`.